# Appropriate location of label reference in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why does this work for lblFlagged:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFlagged" runat="server" Text="x" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblCurrUser" runat="server" Text="MyText" Visible="false"></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1><asp:Label ID="lblMailbox" runat="server" style="color:cornflowerblue; font-size:x-large; font-weight:bold" Text="MyText"></asp:Label></h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="SearchPanel" runat="server">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="MailRepeater" runat="server" onitemcommand="MailRepeater_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="MailRepeater_DataBinding">
                         <HeaderTemplate>  
                             <table>
                                    <tr style="height:7px">
                                        <td style="width:95px"> 
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:110px"> 
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblFromH" runat="server" Text="From"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
```

etc....

And this does not:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lblCurrUser" runat="server" Text="MyText" Visible="false"></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h1><asp:Label ID="lblMailbox" runat="server" style="color:cornflowerblue; font-size:x-large; font-weight:bold" Text="MyText"></asp:Label></h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="SearchPanel" runat="server">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="MailRepeater" runat="server" onitemcommand="MailRepeater_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="MailRepeater_DataBinding">
                         <HeaderTemplate>  
                             <table>
                                    <tr style="height:7px">
                                        <td style="width:95px"> 
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:110px"> 
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblFlagged" runat="server" Text="From"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
```

etc....

**(Note in the first example it's on the first line, and in the second example it's on the last line)**

Notice, in particular, the label "lblFlagged".  In the first case, I can set that value in code-behind if I like.  In the second case, it is underlined in red in the code-behind which tells me it "does not exist in the current context".  It is also missing from the designer.cs file in the 2nd example.

Does this have to do with the UpdatePanel?  Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

`lblFlagged` has been moved to inside the repeater, which makes it no longer directly accessible by your Page or Control as there will now be one label for each item in your repeater's data source.

Use [RepeaterItem.FindControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.findcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the control in places like a loop of the repeaters items or the `OnItemDataBound` event.

```
protected void MailRepeater_DataBinding(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblFlagged");
        lbl.Text = "Hello world";
    }
}
```